# Pandas convert scientific number to normal numbers (float)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe which I read from a csv File, some Columns in this File have numbers in it that are formatted as Scientific notation (something like in the picture below)

[image]

The Problem is that if I check the dtype of the columns it's already formatted as float64, so what can I do to change them like the other number format (like 675537540.2)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've seen that Question but this person is asking to convert the numbers to strings but I want to convert it to a number format that does not display scientific notation like numbers.

Comment: The lambda you used in the approach you mention in the question returns string. I hope you can see how this is confusing.

Comment: Oh sorry about that I didn't realize that!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the display format of floats with `pd.set_option`:

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.2f'.format(x))
```